# member or class variables in python

Tags: python, variables

I come from Java, so I'm getting confused here.

```
class Sample(object):
    x = 100                     # class var?
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.y = value          # instance var?
        z = 300                 # private var? how do we access this outside Sample?
```

What is the difference between the 3 variable declarations?

Comment: Duplicate, duplicate, duplicate... lots and *lots* of questions just like this, lots and *lots* of complete documentation.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: if you're going to call duplicate, at least find the best of the duplicate answers and post a link here.

Comment: To pick a couple of examples which demonstrate all the points of this question: [class and instance variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes), [private variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294764/simulate-private-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
class Sample(object):
    x = 100      
    _a = 1
    __b = 11               
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.y = value      
        self._c = 'private'    
        self.__d = 'more private'
        z = 300
```

In this example:

- `x` is class variable,
- `_a` is private class variable (by naming convention),
- `__b` is private class variable (mangled by interpreter),
- `y` is instance variable,
- `_c` is private instance variable (by naming convention),
- `__d` is private instance variable (mangled by interpreter),
- `z` is local variable within scope of `__init__` method.

In case of single underscore in names, it's strictly a convention. It is still possible to access these variables. In case of double underscore names, they are mangled. It's still possible to circumvent that.

Comment: The dunderscore is rarely used in Python, though. Usually just a single underscore is prepended to signal that the variable is meant for internal use.

Comment: @NiklasB.: single underscore is just indication, while double underscore is enforced by the interpreter.

Comment: I'm just saying that a lot of real-world Python code doesn't make use of this "enforcement", because it doesn't have a real advantage. And yes, you can easily access it anyway through `self._Class__variable`.

Comment: @vartec: _enforced_ is a strong word here.  It is really just name mangled.

Comment: Relevant quote from [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables): "Use one leading underscore only for non-public methods and instance variables. To avoid name clashes with subclasses, use two leading underscores to invoke Python's name mangling rules." It's not more *private* than the single underscore.

Comment: @NiklasB: yeah, and in case of C++ you can access private members via  C call to mangled function name. But what's the point?

Comment: just to confirm. Using _x and __x is same, both are treated the same way?

Comment: @John: No, dunderscore causes the interpreter to enable name mangling, please see the links. But they have the same intent: Marking the variable for internal use.

Comment: @vartec: The point is that Python doesn't have *private* and that the dunderscore is usually not used (unless for implementing special Python methods like `__init__` or `__getattr__`). I think your update reflects the comments here in a sensible way :)

Comment: btw. next line in PEP-8 says *"To avoid name clashes with subclasses, use two leading underscores to invoke Python's name mangling rules."* so it's more like __name -> private _name -> protected

Answer (score 3):

@vartec is spot on. Since you come from Java, however, some clarification is in order:

- Java has `public` and `private` members. Access to `private` members is strictly forbidden, and this is enforced by the language.
- Python only has public members. There is **no** way to enforce something like java's `private` keyword.

  If you want to declare that something is an implementation detail only and shouldn't be relied on by other code, you prefix it with a single underscore - `_variable`, `_function()`. This is a *hint* to other programmers that they shouldn't use that variable or that function, but it is *not enforced.*

  It might seem like a feature has been omitted from Python, but the culture in Python is "everyone is a consenting adult". If you tell other programmers that something is "private" by prefixing it with an underscore, they will generally take the hint.

Comment: Well, technically, you can make a true private, you just have to maim your class by overriding `__setattr__()` to throw an error any time an attempt is made to set the given value from outside the class itself.  Of course, that is VERY un-Pythonic, but if you want to Javaize Python (and I've had a manager that forced us to do that at a previous job), you can make it happen.

Comment: @sr2222: I'm rocking backwards and forwards in the corner as we speak. Ugh.

Comment: @LiAungYip I do believe there's a PEP that says that is the correct response to such a practice.

Comment: @sr2222: You can also circumvent it, I bet.

Comment: "If it runs, it can be hacked."

Comment: It is trivial to circumvent. Either 1) Use the __dict__ directly: "obj.__dict__[name] = value" or 2) If it has a base class, use its __setattr__ "base.__setattr__(obj, name, value)" or 3) patch __setattr__ on your object "obj.__setattr__ = newfun" or if you are desperate 4) do unholy things directly with the ast module.

Comment: @Gurgeh: You bring the black candles, sr2222 can bring the chalk for the pentagram, and I'll bring the sacrificial goat.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be getting the hang of it.  The only one that you were completely wrong about is `z = 300`.  This is a name that is local to the `__init__` method.  Python **never** inserts `self` for you in the same manner that C++ and Java will assume `this` where it can.

One thing to remember as you continue learning Python is that member functions can always be executed as class members.  Consider the following:

```
>>> class Sample(object):
...   def __init__(self, value):
...     self.value = value
...   def get_value(self):
...     return self.value
...
>>> s = Sample(1)
>>> t = Sample(2)
>>> s.get_value()
1
>>> Sample.get_value(s)
1
>>> t.__class__.get_value(s)
1
```

The last three examples all call the *member function* of the `s` object.  The last two use the fact that `get_value` is just an attribute of the `Sample` class that expects to receive an instance of `Sample` as the argument.

Comment: thanks. i came across a article that said by creating a local variable of __init__ method, is like a private var (like in Java). But i couldn't find a way to access z anywhere else.

Comment: also, i lost the link to that article. :(