# How/Why does this work in python? rover._Dog__password()

Tags: python, class, syntax, methods, private

I am doing [the python koan](https://bitbucket.org/gregmalcolm/python_koans/wiki/Home) (for python 2.6) and ecnountered something I don't understand. [One of the files](https://bitbucket.org/gregmalcolm/python_koans/src/81e0997715bb/python%202/koans/about_methods.py) has the following code in line 160:

```
class Dog(object):
    def __password(self):
        return 'password'
```

This

```
rover = Dog()
password = rover.__password()
```

results in an `AttributeError`. That is clear to me. (`__password(self)` is some kind of private method because of the leading two underscores).

But this

```
rover._Dog__password()
```

is a mystery to me. Could some one please explain to me how or why this works or better point me to the docs where this is described?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064202/private-members-in-python

Comment: The first snippet has a typo, the `def` is missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Double underscore :**

> Any identifier of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores,
>   at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with
>   `_classname__spam`, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done without regard
>   to the syntactic position of the identifier, so it can be used to
>   define class-private instance and class variables, methods, variables
>   stored in globals, and even variables stored in instances. private to
>   this class on instances of other classes.

So when you call the `__methodname`, it's exactly a call to `_classname__methodname`. The result is an `AttributeError`

**Single underscore :**

Variables in a class with a leading underscore are simply to indicate to other programmers that the variable should be private. However, nothing special is done with the variable itself.

Python documentation here :

[Python private variables documentation](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Y0dhneqGJToJ:docs.python.org/tutorial/&hl=en&strip=1#private-variables)

Complete post found here :

[What is the meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python)

Comment: No reference or other context for the quote.

Comment: The quote is old; the current version of http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables words it more succinctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I do `rover.__password()` it results in an `AttributeError`. But when I do `rover._Dog__password()` it returns the password. No `AttributeError` raised.

Answer (score 0):

Python does name-mangling of methods that begin with a double-underscore, such that it comes out as you see above. This prevents name clashes in inheritance hierarchies, but does not actually prevent a programmer from invoking the mangled name directly.