# How can i declare a python class function that will be only used by another function of the same class?

Tags: python, class, oop

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class A():
    def fn1(self):
        pass
    def fn2(self):
        pass
```

Now I would want to call function `fn3` inside both `fn1` and `fn2`. The function `fn3` should be such a way that only `fn1` and `fn2` should be able to call it(because `fn3` would be only required by `fn1` or `fn2`).

My Approach would be,

```
class A():
    def fn3(self):
        pass
    def fn1(self):
        fn3()
        pass
    def fn2(self):
        fn3()
        pass
```

Here I see the drawback that `fn3` should have argument `self`(In my case `fn3` does not make use of it). One more drawback would be `fn3` can be called by other objects declared outside the class, which is not necessary.

Comment: If it doesn't need self, make it a static method. If it shouldn't be accessed outside the class, call it `_fn3` - a method with a leading underscore is private by convention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Private members in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064202/private-members-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

@jonrsharpe is correct. Python is considered a "programming language for adults" - in the sense that it doesn't have mechanism to prevent a programmer from doing things you don't want them to do. By adding the double-underscore `__methodName` you are telling other programmers "Don't call this externally." But if they want to, they will :D

If you really want to get pedantic, you could do something similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method) and check the calling method to make sure it's an "authorized" calling method.

I.e.

```
import inspect

class A():
    def fn1(self):
        curframe = inspect.currentframe()
        calframe = inspect.getouterframes(curframe, 2)
        if "fn3" == calframe[1][3]:
            print("This is fn1")
        else: 
            print("NO NO! Bad function '{}'".format(calframe[1][3]))

    def fn2(self):
        curframe = inspect.currentframe()
        calframe = inspect.getouterframes(curframe, 2)
        if "fn3" == calframe[1][3]:
            print("This is fn2")
        else: 
            print("NO NO! Bad function '{}'".format(calframe[1][3]))

    def fn3(self):
        self.fn1()
        print("This is fn3")

    def notfn3(self):
        self.fn1()
        print("This is notfn3")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    o = A()
    o.fn3()
    o.notfn3()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
This is fn1
This is fn3
NO NO! Bad function 'notfn3'
This is notfn3
```

But (IMHO), this is a lot of code, and a lot of additional processing, just to try force someone not to do something you don't want them to do.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you'll find in Python to a "private" method is to declare it with two underscore `__`. In your case:

```
class A():
    def fn1(self):
        pass
    def fn2(self):
        pass
    def __fn3(self):
        pass
```

The `self` part of `__fn3` is just to "bind" the method to the class. You don't need to use it in the method's body.

Depending on how complex `fn3` is, another solution is to create a lambda and pass it to the other functions:

```
__fn3 = lambda self: print("New private bound")

class A():
    def fn1(self, myfunc):
        pass
    def fn2(self, myfunc):
        pass

a = A()
a.fn1(__fn3)
```

Comment: *Single* underscore - double is for name mangling, to avoid collisions.