# How to access private members of a class directly?

Tags: c++, encapsulation

I had a homework which i was asked how to access private members of a class and modify them in c++.I searched about it and i found out that we can do it with typecast and pointers which i know it's an undefined behavior and it should never be used.My question is:
Is it possible to do such thing in other object oriented languages like java or python?

Comment: Did you read a [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/programming.html) book or [C++ tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/) or [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) website? If you did, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62230342/edit) your question to  add some [mre] in your question please. StackOverflow is *not* a *do my homework* website. The answer to your question is: **yes**

Comment: why are you getting taught to break the concept of privacy in the programming...?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes i'm learning c++ and my question is not about it,i'm asking about other object oriented languages,i searched a lot and i didn't find out any thing useful related to my question.

Comment: What other object programming languages do you have in mind? Did you read about the [ObjVLisp object model](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/051f/852ac2883a694c51151c88490603867f5ffb.pdf) ? Or about the [Common Lisp Object System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp_Object_System) ? See [Common Lisp HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/)

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ it's just a challenge we're asked to search about it.I know it's not recommended to use pointers to access private members directly.

Comment: [Python](http://python.org) or C++ (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ...) or Common Lisp (with [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/)...) or even [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) or [Go](http://go-lang.org/) have **[open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) implementations. Download them** and study their source code.

Comment: you could create getter and setter functions for the private members. that is not exactly orthodox but it is possible. you could create a getter that returns a reference to the private member.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ programming language has a [`friend` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend). Friend function can see its friend class' private members. But more young languages don't include this mechanism. Because the mechanism isn't correct for object oriented programming paradigm(for encapsulation).

Comment: Wrong wording. in C++, [`friend` is a specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) not a function (like [`assign` in `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/assign) is)

Comment: Re: "the mechanism isn't correct for object oriented programming paradigm (for encapsulation)" -- that's simply not true. `friend` declarations respect encapsulation; from the class definition you can find everything that can access private members: member functions, friend functions, and member functions of friend classes. That's encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can write a member function that can access and modify private members and make such function public. This is a common way for OOP. However, of course, different languages including C++ may provide hax to modify protected members in another way.

```
class T {
public:
  int get() const {
    return _member;
  } 
  void set(int member) {
    _member = member;
  } 
protected:
  int _member;

};
```

List of well-known hacks

You can easily access any member in Python. Just `dir` whatever you what to hack. [Private members in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064202/private-members-in-python).

You can hack C++ members with template http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2011/12/access-to-private-members-safer.html . It is much safer than use pointers.

You can access private members via reflection in Java https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/.

Generally, any language that lets you debug the code should also reveal somehow protected variables.

Comment: That's right but i was looking for something else,i found this trick for c++:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/can-access-private-data-members-class-without-using-member-friend-function/

Comment: @Askoldllvento Is it possible to do such thing in other object oriented languages?

Comment: Fargol_sh, I added some reference to similar things in other OOL.